# java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input

Tags: java, json, tomcat7, classloader, filereader

I am trying to load file at server(tomcat) deployment time. It is working great in case if i run webapp from eclipse.
But if i make war and deploy it i get this exception

```
java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2173)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2125)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1395)
at com.vems.util.JSONUtil.jsonToObject(JSONUtil.java:76)
at com.vems.util.DataUtil.loadData(DataUtil.java:54)
at com.vems.security.VEMSApplicationObject.loadApplicationSetups(VEMSApplicationObject.java:65)
at com.vems.security.VEMSApplicationObject.startApplication(VEMSApplicationObject.java:53)
at com.vems.security.VEMSContextListener.contextInitialized(VEMSContextListener.java:16)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5099)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5615)
```

I tried `ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();`

and

```
`<build>
<resources>
    <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

`

and

```
`InputStream in=ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("data/budgetSetup.json");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));`
```

But still i am getting same error. Please help me.
Here is my VEMSApplicationObject.java code where fileName = "data/budgetSetup.json";

```
`public String readFile(String fileName, boolean resourceFile) {
        try {
            File file;
            if (resourceFile) {
                ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
                file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
            } else {
                file = new File(fileName);
            }
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            try {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = br.readLine();

                while (line != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                    line = br.readLine();
                }
                return sb.toString();
            } finally {
                fr.close();
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Here is The Exception " + e);
        }
        return "";
    }`
```

Here is The Exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%207.0\webapps\VEMS\WEB-INF\classes\data\budgetSetup.json (The system cannot find the path specified)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load some resources when tomcat starts you can use the following method:

1 - in your web.xml file add:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.mycompany.mywebapp.ContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

2 - in your project create package `com.mycompany.mywebapp` and a class `ContextListener`

```
    package com.mycompany.mywebapp;

    import java.io.File;

    import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
    import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

    public class ContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

        @Override
        public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {

        }

        @Override
        public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
            try {
                String webroot =    event.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
                File myFile = new File(webroot + "/WEB-INF/data/budgetSetup.json");

                /***
                 * do your work with file etc...
                 */
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
                ignored.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

3 - put your json file under /WEB-INF/data/

now tomcat should load your file at startup.

Comment: Thankyou for the solution you provide. It is working great. Please tell me why  

`ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
 file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());`

is not working. This was working since last few months now suddenly stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. tomcat installation path was the issue (`C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0`). Since it contains spaces i.e space between Program & Files and space between Apache, Software & Foundation. So while uploading war this path converts to `C:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%207.0` and leads to `java.io.FileNotFoundException:`.

So install tomcat at `c:\tomcat`